# SoftKeyBoard shows and disappears on EditText in Android DialogFragment developed using support v4 package

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

I am developing an android application using support v4 package where I used Fragments in which I am using DialogFragment . I contains EditText . When I click on EditText to enter some text , the softkeyboard just comes and disappears and I am not able to enter text.

Can anyone help me in sorting out this problem.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

use below code

```
((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).showSoftInput(et_usename, 0);
```

where et_usename is the editext id like `EditText et_usename=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_usename);`

Answer (score 0):

You can also open it on touch event ,

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (v.getId() == R.id.receiverText) {
        receiver.selectAll();
        receiver.requestFocus();
        manager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        manager.showSoftInput(receiver, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);

    }
```

receiver is my edittext